# Word as neural network input

Tags: neural-network

Task:
I have combination of letters, e.g. "hafe", "cool", "zcna", and I want to learn NN to decide whether this combination of letters is "beautiful" or not.
I tried to convert letter to array by the next algorithm: `arr[i] = word[i] - 'a' == i ? 1 : 0, so arr[i] is 1 if it is current letter, and 0 otherwise.
Input for NN is concatenation of these arrays.
I used perceptron with such input, but it doesn't work.
Any ideas? Maybe there is better option for converting words to the input? Or I need to use different architecture?

**UPD**

Code I used for learning NN. JS + Synaptic.

```
const network = new synaptic.Architect.Perceptron(26 * 7, 100, 1)

const feedInitialData = () => {
    data = data
        .concat(names
            .slice(0, 10000)
            .filter(name => name.length == 7)
            .map(wordToArray)
            .map(input => ({input, output: [1]}))
        )

    for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        let word = randomString(7)
        data.push({input : wordToArray(word), output : [0]})
    }

    network.trainer.train(data, { 
        iterations: 10000000,
        cost: synaptic.Trainer.cost.MSE,
    })

    console.log(network.activate(data[0].input))
    data = []
}
```

Comment: Maybe post some of your code?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu updated

Comment: Maybe try something along the lines of word2vec?